# full-duplex TCP/IP stream socket connection vs PollingDuplexHttpBinding vs WSDualHttpBinding

Tags: wcf, http, streaming, tcp

full-duplex TCP/IP stream socket connection vs `PollingDuplexHttpBinding` vs `WSDualHttpBinding` 
I want to know -

- What is same
- What is different
- Some comparing tables
- Some articles
- Where what can\cannot be used 
  etc.

Comment: This blog should answer a couple of your questions http://tomasz.janczuk.org/